# compute mfcc for audio file over fixed chunks and save them separately

Tags: python, numpy, librosa

**WHAT I WAS ABLE TO DO:**
Currently I'm able to generate mfcc for all files in a given folder and save them as follows:

```
def gen_features(in_path, out_path):
    src = in_path + '/'
    output_path = out_path + '/'
    sr = 22050
    path_to_audios = [os.path.join(src, f) for f in os.listdir(src)]

    for audio in path_to_audios:
        audio_data = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=22050)[0] # getting y
        mfcc_feature_list = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio_data,sr=sr) # create mfcc features
        np.savetxt(blah blahblah , mfcc_feature_list, delimiter ="\t")


gen_features('/home/data','home/data/features')
```

**DIFFICULTY:**
my input audio recordings are pretty long, each is atleast 3-4 hours long.
this program is very inefficient as the file size after `np.savetxt` is becoming pretty big ~ 1.5MB txt file for 1 minute of audio.  I plan to combine mfcc with more features in the future. So the saved file text size will explode.  I want to keep it smaller 5 minute chunks for easy of processing.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO:**
add one more parameter `len` to gen_features, this must specify the length of audio to be processed at a time.

So if the input audio `abc.mp3`is 13 minutes long, and I specify `len = 5` meaning 5minutes,

then mfcc's should be computed for [0.0,5.0) [5.0,10.0) and [10.0,13.0] and they should be saved
as
`mfcc_filename_chunk_1.csv`
`mfcc_filename_chunk_2.csv`
`mfcc_filename_chunk_3.csv`

Like this I want to do it for all files in that directory.
I want to do achieve this using librosa.

I am unable to get any ideas on how to proceed.

More awesome thing to do would be, compute this over overlapping intervals, example if `len =5` is passed , 
then
`chunk one should be over [0.0,5.1]`
`chunk two should be over [5.0,10.1]`
`chunk three should be over [10.0,13.0]`